# key Code of backspace button in type script

Tags: angular

How to get backspace key Code in type Script. I have tried my method but failed to get the key code of backspace button in type script
I have used it

```
1)document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
      console.log(event.which);
 }) 
2)let keyCode = window.event ? e.keyCode : event.which;
    if (keyCode !== 8) {
    }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [keydown documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)? It’s `e.code` or `e.key` depending on whether you want readable characters or actual layout-independent codes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.